# Error importing user to models

Tags: django

I'm trying to import "User" to models:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

and in my model I have:

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

but when I do syncdb It shows this error:

```
ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field blog.Post.author: auth.User
```

I'm running django 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the commands makemigrations and migrate. You can find detailed info in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#workflow).

As an additional suggestion, don't reference the User model directly. Do it the right way ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model)):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```